# Nativescript-vue: how to apply a new theme using default app.scss?

Tags: nativescript-vue

I initialized a new project using

```
tns create <project_name> --vue
```

So I've the file `~/App/app.scss`

```
// Import app variables
@import 'app-variables';

// Import the theme’s main ruleset - both index and platform specific.
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/index';
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/platforms/index.android';

// Import common styles
@import 'app-common';
```

I'd like to try one of the themes, for example 'aqua' or 'brown'.

**What must I add and/or changes?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening `_app-variables.scss` I found this at start

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/light';
```

I changed to

```
@import '~nativescript-theme-core/scss/brown';
```

Then commented *all* the overrides of the variables.

Then in my `Home.vue`, in the `style` section, I commented the use of `$dark_accent`.

In this way I can simply switch theme using the first row of `_app-variables.scss`